# Build does not include source with file suffix

Tags: go

Compiling under ubuntu

> Linux ip 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
>   x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

with golang version

> go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64

The files I have:

> daemon_darwin.go  daemon_freebsd.go  daemon.go    daemon_linux.go 
>   daemon_windows.go  LICENSE  os.go  README.md

The command I'm executing

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -x
```

The output I'm getting

```
WORK=/tmp/go-build026556308 mkdir -p
$WORK/github.com/VividCortex/godaemon/_obj/ mkdir -p
$WORK/github.com/VividCortex/ cd
/root/go/src/github.com/VividCortex/godaemon
/home/jenkinsBuilder/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/Go_1.8/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile
-o $WORK/github.com/VividCortex/godaemon.a -trimpath $WORK -p github.com/VividCortex/godaemon -complete -buildid
398bd35cdb7ed0aa42a3e6ea64677925441c29cb -D
_/root/go/src/github.com/VividCortex/godaemon -I $WORK -pack ./daemon.go ./os.go
# github.com/VividCortex/godaemon ./daemon.go:167: undefined: GetExecutablePath
```

we can see that daemon_darwin.go is **not** being included in the compile command, although I've added `GOOS=darwin`

If I try using `GOOS=windows`, it builds correctly, and daemon_windows.go is being added

Comment: Speculation: Any build tags in daemon_darwin.go which disable its compilation?

Comment: @Volker nope. I think this is disabled on the golang linux go distribution. I tried adding ./daemon_darwin.go manually to the compile command and I got en error, which makes me think this is disabled on purpose.

Comment: The `_darwin.go` uses `cgo`. You can't simply cross-compiles without installing the needed toolchain.

Comment: @putu got it. I just used an osx slave instead :| thanks!

Comment: This is not disabled on linux, and it works for me with a trivial example. We need more info from your files. Does `daemon_darwin.go` has the same package declaration as other .go files in the same folder?

Comment: @icza - I'm just trying to compile a darwin binary on ubuntu of github.com/VividCortex/godaemon

Comment: @Shai The darwin implementation of that specific package calls a function implemented in C, so you need cgo as mentioned by putu. You are able to compile it for windows, because the windows implementation does not call a C function (it's pure Go).